# How to get a remote URI

Tags: git

I'd like to get an address of my remote repository, ideally one line only. Ideal would be something like

```
$ git remote show origin fetch_url --some-params-im-not-aware-of
git://github.com/ask/celery.git
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simple: `git config remote.origin.url`

Comment: discussion of source control is programming related, FYI :)

Comment: Ah, sorry. Command-line APIs also seem to work on both sites.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way of showing the URLs that each of your remotes refers to is `git remote -v`.  For example:

```
$ git remote -v
origin git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
git remote get-url origin
```